# Geometric argument for: ${\|(\mathbf A \times \mathbf B)\|}^2 + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B)^2 = \|\mathbf A\|^2 \|\mathbf B\|^2$

Tags: geometry, vectors

A and B are any two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.
I have drawn lots of pretty diagrams but I can't see that equation on on a 3D graph. I am not looking for an algebraic proof, as I've already done that.

Comment: It is the same as $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1$

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is geometric enough for your taste, but if we regard the vector ${\bf A} = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ as the imaginary quaternion $a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$ and similarly for $\bf B$, this follows from unwinding the quaternionic definitions of dot and cross products together with the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, you can represent the magnitude of the vector product,
$\newcommand{A}{\mathbf A}\newcommand{B}{\mathbf B}
\lVert\A\times\B\rVert,$
as the area of the parallelogram two of whose sides are formed by the two vectors, as show in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1304618).
From this it can be seen that if we take the side formed by $\B$ as the base of the parallelogram, then the height of the parallelogram--that is, the length of a perpendicular segment dropped from the vertex formed by the tip of vector $\A$ to the side formed by the vector $\B$--is just
$$
\frac{\lVert\A\times\B\rVert}{\lVert \B\rVert}.
$$
The length of the projection of $\A$ onto $\B,$ however, is
$$
\frac{\A\cdot\B}{\lVert \B\rVert}.
$$
The perpendicular segment, the projection, and the vector $\A$ itself
form a right triangle. Apply the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As stated in the picture the area of parallelogram is $||\vec a\times \vec b||=ab\ sin(\theta)$.

If we set $x$ the distance between $O$ and the intersection point of altitude h with $\vec a$ then $x=(\vec a\ .\vec b)/a$ as a projection of $\vec b$ on $\vec a$ (well in the drawing, considering the segments representing the vectors).

In this rectangle triangle we have $\displaystyle{cos(\theta)=\frac{adjacent\  side}{hypothenuse}=\frac xb}$

Pythagora's theorem : $x^2+h^2=b^2\iff\frac{(\vec a\,.\vec b)^2}{a^2}+\frac{||\vec a\times\vec b||}{a^2}=b^2.$